# calling a function based on run time types of a base-class pointer in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dispatch

I'm trying to write a function that calls the proper sub-function based on the run time type of its arguments. I feel like there must be a more proper way to do it. I tried using the type_id() operator but I don't think that's the answer either. Basically, I'm trying to get the run-time type of an object that I'm storing as a pointer to its base class.

I need to store them as base class pointers so I can hold them in another object. I'm currently using a "ShapeType" member on each child class to distinguish them, but that seems like a hacky workaround. I'm just feeling bad about the design in general, where did I go wrong? Should I ditch this dispatch function and use functions?

```
bool Physics::CheckCollision(CollisionData* i_collision)
{
    Shape::ShapeType shape1 = i_collision->bodyA->shape->GetType();
    Shape::ShapeType shape2 = i_collision->bodyB->shape->GetType();
    bool collisionOccured = false;
    if ((shape1 == Shape::Circle) && (shape2 == Shape::Circle))
    {
        collisionOccured = ResolveCircleToCircleCollision(i_collision);
    }
    else if ((shape1 == Shape::Rectangle) && (shape2 == Shape::Rectangle))
    {
        collisionOccured = ResolveRectToRectCollision(i_collision);
    }
    else if ((shape1 == Shape::Rectangle) && (shape2 == Shape::Circle))
    {
        collisionOccured = ResolveRectToCircleCollision(i_collision);
        RigidBody* temp = i_collision->bodyA;
        i_collision->bodyA = i_collision->bodyB;
        i_collision->bodyB = temp;
    }
    else if ((shape1 == Shape::Circle) && (shape2 == Shape::Rectangle))
    {
        RigidBody* temp = i_collision->bodyA;
        i_collision->bodyA = i_collision->bodyB;
        i_collision->bodyB = temp;
        collisionOccured = ResolveRectToCircleCollision(i_collision);
        temp = i_collision->bodyA;
        i_collision->bodyA = i_collision->bodyB;
        i_collision->bodyB = temp;
    }
    return collisionOccured;
}
```

Comment: This is the kind of problem that `virtual` methods are meant to solve, so that you don't need to know the exact types involved. But, if you absolutely need to know what particular derived type a base pointer is pointing at, use `dynamic_cast` for that.

Comment: The canonical solution for this is multi dispatch, which is not supported by C++. You either have to use a visitor or a bunch of dynamic_cast & test (which is isomorphic to what you are doing). See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C++

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone! It looks like I'm not that far off after all. I could use the visitor pattern to remove a need for any cast, but I think I might want to keep this collision check in its own separate "Physics" class like I'm already doing. I could also trade my custom types for dnymaic cast checks, but apparently that's quite expensive. I'll mull it over. Either way thanks for leading me on a very informative Wikipedia deep dive.